# Echo Program Help

Tags: python, user-input

I need some guidance on how best to run this program. Im trying to come up with a python program that accepts input from the user and prints them out until the word quit is inputted in which the program quits but not before printing the inputs twice..

For example

2.0'
6.0
3.5
quit
2.0
6.0
3.5
2.0
6.0
3.5

Thanks so much for helping =)

```
inputs = []

inp = raw_input(" Enter number or quit: ")

while inp!="quit":  
        inp = float(inp)
        inputs.append(inp)  
        inp = raw_input("Enter number or quit': ")



if inp == "quit":  
    print inputs, "quit", inputs * 2
```

now how do i get them on seperate lines?

Comment: i can get the input in fine but i cant get the output to print out right without the loop going all infinite on me :(

Comment: Suggestion on your posting of code: 4 spaces before a line of code marks it as such (backticks allow this inline). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for a full rundown of the markup.

Comment: @justin: "the loop going all infinite on me ".  Please focus on this.  Why do you think the loop "goes all infinite".  Please **update** the question with a short sentence on why the loop **must** be infinite.  Please explain which statements are in the body of the loop and **why** those statements are in the body of the loop.  PLease **update** your question with these facts.

Comment: @justin: +1 for following suggestions and trying to make it work rather than letting others just do it for you.

Comment: its hard but im learning that way :) Any clue on how i can get the output to write on seperate lines as my example above?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited to improve visual clarity:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env python
2 
3 if __name__ == "__main__":
4   inputs = []
5   while True:
6     inp = raw_input("Enter number|`quit': ")
7     if inp.lower() == "quit":
8       break
9     try: inp = float(inp)
10     except:
11       print "Not a number, ignored"
12       continue
13     print inp
14     inputs.append(inp)
15   for i in inputs: print i
```

Comment: First, you should guide him as this is a homework. I have edited your answer but you should provide the code and not copy paste with lines. It helps to at least format your code.

Comment: @pyfunc: I pasted with the line numbers to make it easy to comment since justin may want comments on it.

Comment: thanks guys! im getting closer cause im using a list :P almost there.

Comment: I did not down vote it but this is a bad practice since it would make it cumbersome for any one to try out the code. Standard way of adding comments to code is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited answer]

You are converting raw_input to float and then trying to compare with a string. Shouldn't you compare first and then print.

Apart from this mistake you are doing fine!

Comment: hmm i get the raw_input part but i cant seem to get the output right.

Comment: @justin: I guess, you should publish what you have done so that folks on SO can guide you rather than do your homework. This way, you would learn.

Comment: ok im a newbie when it comes to programming but i put what i have.

Comment: @justin: Edited my answer and this should help you rework your solution.